# Using \n is placing the previous character on a new line

Tags: python

Im trying to take some values for a list and use them for a game config, however when i'm writing to the config it is not using the layout it should.

I have the text file called item_index.txt and the contents:

```
 <number>: <name>
```

My code is this:

```
file = open("item_index.txt", "r", encoding="utf8")
    with open("config.cfg", "w") as config:
    lines = file.readlines()
    lines.sort()
    config.write('"Paints"\n{\n')
    for skin in lines:
        skin = skin.replace(": ",":")
        new_skin = skin.split(":")
        config.write('    "' + new_skin[1] + '"' + '\n')
        config.write('    {\n')
        config.write('        "paint"    "' + new_skin[0] + '"\n')
        config.write('        "wear"    "0.000000000000000001"\n')
        config.write('        "quality"    "3"\n')
        config.write('    }\n')
config.write("}")
```

Theoretically it should write the config like this:

```
    "<name>"
    {
        "paint"    "<number>"
        "wear"    "0.000000000000000001"
        "quality"    "3"
    }
```

But for some reason it is outputting this:

```
    "<name>
"
    {
        "paint"    "<number>"
        "wear"    "0.000000000000000001"
        "quality"    "3"
    }
```

Does anyone know what would be causing this? My guess is that it is something to do with the \n that is after, but i'm completely clueless after trying things like just using one config.write and placing the whole thing in there. Sorry if this is vague.

Comment: Please, Python's string class has a couple different methods, and two mini-lanaguages for interpolating strings an values. The **last** thing you should be doing is trying to assemble a string closign and opening quotes and concatenating with "+" - and even less making several calls to the  `write` method -as the language also has mutli-line string support, AND cross line string concatenation for whoever does not like that.

Comment: @jsbueno: to be exact, three method of interpolating -- `%`-based, `{}`-based, and `$`-based.

Comment: Also, why not JSON?

Comment: The output the OP needs does not seem to be json or json-compatible - that is why I did not mention it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to strip the newline from the end of new_skin:

```
new_skin = skin.strip('\n').split(":")
```

Answer (score 0):

As for your question, your problem is that you have a `"\n"` at the end of each line of the read from the source file - just strip it before using its value - `new_skin[1].strip()`  instead of `new_skin[1]`

But please, for your sake, checkout the tens of ways of handlign and interpolating strings in Python - you are just doing the worst thing possible for readability and maintanability.

```
file = open("item_index.txt", "r", encoding="utf8")
template = """\
{sk1}
{{
    "paint"  "{sk0}"
    "wear"   "0.000000000000000001"
    "quality" "3"
}}
"""
with open("config.cfg", "w") as config:
    config.write('"Paints"\n{\n')
    for skin in sorted(file):
        new_skin = skin.split(":")
        config.write(template.format(sk0=new_skin[0].strip(), sk1=new_skin[1].strip(), wear=wear)
    config.write("}")
```

Comment: You are going to have to replace the literal `{`s in the template with `{{` or `.format()` will error.